# Google Cloud Monitor - add different projects in one dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard, google-cloud-monitoring

I have one organization which has 3 projects. The first one (a) has 10 VM instances. The second one (b) has 15 VM instances and the last one (c) has 3 VM instances.

I want to configure my dashboard to show all the  metrics from all instances of all the projects, right now I can only get the selected projects vm instances.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review the workspaces documentation for GCP monitoring.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces

It seems you need a monitoring host project and you can then add monitoring workspaces from different projects to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll read that and update.