# firebase functions - best way to monitor it on console.cloud.google

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I got multiple projects on firebase, and I am mainly using (JavaScript/TypeScript - with cron scheduled) function logic (with notifications via Twitter, storing data in firestore, and doing the business logic on data received from REST calls)

Due to the recent changes in firebase, I am being redirected to google cloud for doing logs reviews, etc.

My recent idea is to create a sensible dashboard that will give me a clear overview of what is happening in my project. The problem is I am not familiar with google cloud.

So after this long introduction.

What is Your preferred approach to monitoring Your typescript functions?
Is there any dashboard setup that gives You just the perfect amount of information?

Comment: Like monitoring a specific cloud function? You can just refer to "Metrics" and "Logs" tab on the Cloud Functions console then. That should provide you most of the details. Or are you trying to get some sort of aggregated data?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thank you for your answer! :) 
That is what I am doing now - I noticed that there are a lot of options in creating a dashboard. 
My perfect solution would be: 
- dashboard for monitoring a whole stg-environment (multiple projects) in one dashboard - number of errors, average usage statistics, etc. 
- dashboard for a single project - so similar to the one with the whole environment, plus some custom details for said project (number of instances of functions, avg times, etc)

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943209/google-cloud-monitor-add-different-projects-in-one-dashboard) which also mentions the document for Overview of viewing metrics for multiple projects and also check this [quickstart](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/621?parent=catalog)